# HashMap implementation: --- hashcode

Tags: c++, hash, operator-keyword, hashcode, bit

```
template<class KEY, class VALUE>
unsigned int HashMap<KEY, VALUE>::hashCode(KEY key)
{
    unsigned int k = key & 0xffffffff; //error: no match for ‘operator&’ in ‘key & 4294967295u’
    k += ~(k<<9);
    k ^= (k>>14);
    k += (k<<4);
    k ^= (k>>10);
    return k;
};
```

As you see, I'm trying to implement the hashCode by manipulating bits in the object. Obviously, bit operators don't easily apply to user-defined objects.

I want to take some bits of an object of any type, given its memory location, and manipulate the bits as I wish. Then I'll reinterpret the bits as int and apply bitwise operators to the int.

Does that sound like a good idea? And How can I take bits from objects of ANY TYPE at a given memory location?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a terrible idea, because it doesn't respect the type's definition of equality. A type might be defined so that several different representations can be considered equal (think of a `std::string`, which contains a couple of pointers, and nothing else. Two strings might be equal (both contain `"hello world"`, but have different pointers because they point to different blocks of memory, and so your hash key implementation would return *different* hash key for two equal objects.

In other words, you'd break the hash table, and users would be unable to find the objects they put in the table.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea.

Without knowing details of the object's members, you don't know which bits are actually useful or relevant to hash. For instance, due to alignment issues, there can be gaps of memory between the actual data members, and the gaps are never initialized so they're full of garbage data. Or, if the data member is a char array string, all the bytes past the null terminator are garbage and should not contribute to the hash.

There are ways of implementing simple reflection in C++ using macros which can do what you really want here (i.e. find all the struct's members and types), but I don't know of any good open-source ones off the top of my head. We have one in my codebase at work (which has a template which does exactly what you want, i.e. make a hash function for an arbitrary struct) but I can't share it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take some bits of an object of any type, given its memory
>   location, and manipulate the bits as I wish.

What you are saying here is you want to manipulate the underlying bit representation of the datastructure as a series of bits.

This approach can work only on primitive types e.g. ints, chars etc.

In your example `KEY` could be anything and the underlying bits is as much as the size of the structure so your `and` operation doesn't really help.

Additionally `KEY` could be a derived class and start hitting on virtual pointer address etc which are part of the underlying structure.

In any case, the code (even if you decided to go that way and some friend expert in SO could guide you) would be way too complicated in my opinion.

The best approach would be to `hash` each of the members of the object.This is the approach followed in Java at least and is straightforward to implement

Comment: It won't even work on primitive types due to alignment leaving gaps, and char arrays having garbage after the null terminator. See my earlier answer for details on this.

Comment: You are right.I had in mind the actual primitive as in java where the hash of an int for example is the number itself